(LINUX) use echo and grep to delete multiple files
I have 4 files in my current directory: '#cos#', ab.txt, cos~, file.txt. I want to delete all files with the word "cos" in them, which just also happen to be the only words with the letters 'c', 'o', and 's' in them. I've set up the following:
echo * | grep -E '[cos]' | <idk what to put here>

in the , what should I put so as to delete all the files that the command is fed?

echo * | grep -E '[cos]' | xargs rm

Why do you think it's appropriate to use either echo or grep for this purpose?

@John3136, that doesn't work correctly for all possible filenames -- look at how xargs handles whitespace, quotes, &c. (Also, in the spec for echo, note the caveats about backslashes, and consider behavior in presence of files named exactly -n)

(also, why match [cos] instead of just cos?)

Moreover, filenames containing literal newlines are possible, and combining echo and grep is irretrievably, unfixably broken for such names. Yes, it's possible to whip up a simple pipeline that looks like it works in the easy cases, but if you use the practice in any kind of security-sensitive context you're setting yourself up for pain. Don't.

@CharlesDuffy because I wasn't thinking lol. Still kinda works in my case tho

@CharlesDuffy thanks, I'll take your advice and learn other ways to do it. I'm just starting to learn shell and so I kind of just wanted to test the pipeline to check my understanding. But yes, no doubt not the best or most secure way to do it

Think about printf '%s\0' * | grep -zE 'cos' | xargs -0 rm -- as a more reliable alternative on a GNU system with grep -z. Or do the sane thing and use find . -name '*cos"' -exec rm -- {} + or rm -- *cos* instead (depending on whether recursion is called for); those latter suggestions will work without GNU tools.

Regarding "that's exactly what I was looking for" - no, it definitely is not. It MAY work for some specific set of files you currently are testing with but it will fail with other file names, on other platforms, etc. echo will mangle file names, grep '[cos]' will find files with just a c or o or s in them, xargs will split file names with white space and remove the wrong files, etc. Its worse than just "not the best way to do it", its 100% NOT the way to do it.

first try locating the correct files in current directory:
grep -l "cos" *
This command will list the files having string "cos" in them.
Once your are sure these are the files you want to delete.
rm -f $(grep -l "cos" *)

the simplest way to achieve your goal is to use the find command:
# find <path> -name "*cos*" -exec rm {} \;


Is OP asking for "cos" in the file name or cos in the contents ? If just the name then rm *cos* would do it.

Yes, I was asking for "cos" in the file name
